# Toggling Navigation Icon Back

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, navigation, font-awesome

I am building a dropdown navigation menu and am trying to use icons that toggle back and forth when the menu item is clicked. I have been able to get it to the point where the icon will toggle, but the trouble I am having is that when another next menu option is selected, I cannot get the previous icon to toggle back.

So, for example, when the first option is clicked, the plus sign turns to minus, which is great. But when I click the second option I cannot seem to figure out how to get the first option to go back to plus.

```js
$('#category-tabs li a').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="category-tabs">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javscript:void(0);">Category 1   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javscript:void(0);">Category 2   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javscript:void(0);">Category 3   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jbumbico/w58yfwh6/1/) if that helps at all.

Thank you for taking a look at this, I am pretty new at this and can use all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the minus icon and add the plus icon:

```
$('#category-tabs li a').click(function() {
  var $icon = $(this).find('i');
  var isOpen = $icon.hasClass('fa-minus-circle');
  $("#category-tabs").find('i').removeClass('fa-minus-circle').addClass('fa-plus-circle');
  if (isOpen) {
    $icon.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
  } else {
    $icon.removeClass().addClass('fa fa-minus-circle');
  }
```

});

working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zcqrmn66/17/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad could help, please accept the answer if you don't mind.